# How do i hide the keyboard from showing when EditText is clicked on

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-widget, listener

I have multiple text views and one edit text widget.

This is my problem:
After my app starts, When i click on the EditText, it shows up with the keyboard. I've setup an onTouchListener performing some actions, this is working properly.

However, in my textView onClick listener, I sets the EditText focusable to false whenever i click on any of the textView underneath the EditText widget. This works properly but the keyboard doesn't go away.

So how do I hide the keyboard after setting focusable() to false in my text_view onClicklistener.

I don't intend to disable the keyboard, this is what I want; after clicking on the EditText which shows the keyboard, if i click on the textView underneath, I want EditText's setFocusable set to false (which is working) and also hide keyboard (which i have no idea how to achieve).

Here is my code

```
public class FacilityScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_facilty_screen);

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_location);
    editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            view.setFocusable(true);
            view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

            if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == motionEvent.getAction()) {

                    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.enter_location);
                    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}

public void text_view(View view) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_location);
    editText.setFocusable(false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3F51B5"));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your method after

```
editText.setFocusable(false);
editText.clearFocus();
```

if that doesn't work use the method below to dismiss the keyboard

```
 public static void dismissKeyboard(EditText editText, Context context) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

hope this helps.